# Multiple Select in jquery 1.3.2 does not work in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

If I have the multiselect directly on the page, it works and displays fine; but if I have the multiselect on the popup, the display is wrong and it only shows one element. Can someone tell me why and how to fix it?

I show my problem in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uvvm40Lu/4/ (click on the popup link).

And this is my code:

```
<select id="transactionType0" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" size="7">
  <option value="Mo">Mo</option>
  <option value="Di">Di</option>
  <option value="Mi">Mi</option>
  <option value="Do">Do</option>
  <option value="Fr">Fr</option>
  <option value="Sa">Sa</option>            
  <option value="So">So</option>            
</select>
<a href="#popup1" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">popup</a>
<div id="popup1" data-role="popup" data-overlay-theme="a">
<select id="transactionType1" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" size="7">
  <option value="Mo">Mo</option>
  <option value="Di">Di</option>
  <option value="Mi">Mi</option>
  <option value="Do">Do</option>
  <option value="Fr">Fr</option>
  <option value="Sa">Sa</option>            
  <option value="So">So</option>            
</select>
```

Comment: @DerGolem a lot of code is hidden because it is not properly formatted and your edit is to erase a "Thank you"? Seriously?

Comment: Well, thanks are useless, anyway, don't you agree?

Comment: Thanks may be useless, but that doesn't justify such a poor edition. Adding a few white spaces in the code would have improved this question a thousand times more than removing a useless "Thank you"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the popup documentation: http://api.jquerymobile.com/1.3/popup/, you will see that it does not support popup chaining (i.e. one popup open over another popup).  Unfortunately the multi-select uses a popup to display the choices, so it violates the popup chaining issue.

There is a jQM plugin called simpledialog2 that does allow chaining: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/, or you can roll your own.